# iOS YUCIRGBtonecurve : Cannot use sRGB texture binding with format BGRA8 for sampler 0 in kernel 'filterKernel'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, opengl-es

I'm using YUCIRGBToneCurve library , this class keep crashing my camera . 
At the moment camera start capturing/

```
Cannot use sRGB texture binding with format BGRA8 for sampler 0 in kernel 'filterKernel'.
```

My custom view rendered with CIContext created by EAGLContext

I have tried  sRGB Linear & deviceRGB , both gave me no luck.

```
 self.openGLContext = [[EAGLContext alloc]initWithAPI: kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
    self.openGLView = [[GLKView alloc]initWithFrame:view.frame context:self.openGLContext];
    self.coreimageContext = [CIContext contextWithEAGLContext:self.openGLContext];
    self.coreimageContext = [CIContext contextWithEAGLContext:self.openGLContext options:@{kCIContextWorkingColorSpace:(id) CFBridgingRelease(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB())}];
```